# What parts of the AWS should I use for a web portal?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am currently working on a web portal for a foundation. Applicants for a grant will receive access data in advance independently of this portal. New applications will then be created and processed in the portal itself. Once an application is complete, it is sent off. Later the application will be approved or rejected.

There are a number of technical specifications on which I have no influence. The frontend should be implemented using Html+Javascript. The backend should use the Amazon Web Services (AWS). If there is a need to program something for the backend - then C# should be used.

I know how to implement the classic client-server solution. At the moment, however, AWS offers me an unmanageable set of services. And here I'm hoping for suggestions as to which of the services I should take a closer look at. Ideally, no complete 'server solution' should run on a virtual server. Instead, Lambda functions are mentioned again and again. So would Amazon RDS and AWS Lambda be a sensible and sufficient combination? Did I miss something?

Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: What is your database choice and what kind of portal are you deploying read heavy or write heavy and what is your requirements for scaling and TPS etc ,will help you to suggest proper architecture

Comment: Does it have to be a relational database or is a NoSQL solution viable, such as DynamoDB?

Comment: Maybe something like this https://medium.com/employbl/tutorial-for-building-a-web-application-with-amazon-s3-lambda-dynamodb-and-api-gateway-6d3ddf77f15a?

Comment: https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-and-serverless-computing-79032206

Comment: At the moment there is no fixed specification regarding the database. I was thinking of a relational DB. However, the amount of data is probably not very large and does not necessarily have to be relationally organized.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use AWS S3 to server HTML, CSS, JS, Images and other static content. You could use AWS Lambda via AWS API Gateway to serve as a backend. AWS Lambda would then connect to AWS RDS or AWS DynamoDB if you would prefer a NoSQL solution.

[image: AWS Architecture]
Image taken from [AWS Github repo](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-serverless-workshops/blob/master/WebApplication/images/wildrydes-complete-architecture.png)

You can get a more detailed description of how to set this up at
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-serverless-workshops/tree/master/WebApplication/

Comment: I will take a look at that. Thank you,